# loose newel post with some type of plate underneath, how to tighten

Tags: wood, stairs

I have a newel post with a plate underneath, see attached picture. It is wobbly. I have tried using pocket screws to secure the post, however they get stuck at what I believe to be this plate. What is this plate? How can I remove it/tighten the post?

[image: view1]
[image: view2]

Comment: You won't be able to do much without more access. Is the basement below unfinished? Would you consider disassembling the railing section?

Comment: I thought that may be the case. It is a split level and the post is in the upper level.. no access below without tearing a wall out.

Comment: Does the wood move with respect to the bracket, or does the bracket move with respect to the floor?

Comment: The bracket and the post both move with respect to the floor.